# Would slavery reparations be considered Bills of Attainder and hence Illegal in the US?

Tags: united-states, slavery, reparations

Recently, a few aspiring 2020 Democratic Presidential candidates (specifically Kamala Harris and Elizabeth Warren) have spoken out in favor of "reparations" to black people for American Slavery, which was abolished over 150 years ago.

Mirriam Dictionary defines a "Bill of Attainder" as:

> a legislative act that imposes punishment without a trial

Bills of Attainder are specifically prohibited by the US Constitution in Article 1, Section 9.

Of course, the idea behind banning Bills of Attainder was to prevent abuse whereby legislatures would target groups of people and pass laws summarily punishing them for perceived actions or transgressions.

Would any Bill establishing "slavery reparations" not have to be considered an **illegal Bill of Attainder** since they specifically target non-black people and slate them for punishment without a trial?

Comment: As @Joshua pointed out, "corruption of blood" fits better.

Comment: " slate them for punishment without a trial" - Assuming these reparations would be funded through the Federal budget: As a US taxpayer I disagree with the notion that me being taxed and my tax-dollars being put towards reparations is any kind of "punishment". It's just my tax-dollars at work.

Comment: @Dai: You could easily find US taxpayers - me, for instance - who'd disagree with that.

Comment: @jamesqf Does money spent on wars punish pacifists?  Do tax cuts for oil producers punish environmentalists?  I challenge you to find a single person who is completely satisfied with how all federal tax dollars are spent.  This argument is ludicrous.  It sounds like something out of the sovereign citizen movement.

Comment: @jamesqf The taxes anyone of us pays, will necessarily also be used for things we don't need (eg. for schools for someone who's childless), don't want, or things we simply disagree with.  Once the taxes are collected, the Government spend it as they see fit - just like you spend your pay-check without your employer weighing in.

Comment: @JimmyJames: There's a difference between a policy which individuals may or may not agree with, such as wars, and taking money from some people for the direct benefit of others.

Comment: @jamesqf: You do know what most taxes get spent on, right? **People's wages**. Even if you buy expensive goods (e.g. fighter planes), that money is still being predominantly spent on the wages of the plane builders (albeit not necessarily Americans). Even for raw resources, most money is again spent on people's effort in acquiring said resources. **Money goes to people**. Objects have no concept/need of money. ALL government expenses end up being given to particular people to their benefit. The distinction whether it's a wage or a post-factum recompensation is moot.

Comment: @jamesqf: Oh and to precede a "but these people didn't do anything to earn the money!" argument, when the government decides to pay reparations, it is communally agreed that paying the reparations is the right course of action. And while you clearly disagree (and that's fine), communal agreement does not require _unanimous_ agreement. Such a requirement would perpetually deadlock pretty much any legislature.

Comment: @Flater: Re "it is communally agreed", that's really getting away from the question of whether it's actually legal.  There's also the question of whether you could actually get such communal agreement, as I was trying to point out.

Comment: @jamesqf: The voting in of a person who runs on a platform of making those reparations _is_ the communal agreement. That is the core principle of a representative democracy. There is nothing illegal about the government paying recompensation for (a) person(s) who was/were damaged by governmental actions. The question focuses on the inference that having to pay it is a "punishment" to the tax payer. The question does not focus on who gets paid by these reparations, but rather those who have to pay them.

Comment: @jamesqf: As a basic example: if the President's motorcade hits a civilian and recompensates them for the harm inflicted, should we now hold general elections or a census to see if a communal agreement can be made that the person should be recompensated? How about if they hit two people? How about three? You can see where I'm going with this. Reparations for slavery are no different from recompensation due to harm inflicted.

Comment: @Flater: They certainly are different.  No person alive today has been a slave. Further, slavery was a pretty much universal human institution, so basically all of us have ancestors who were slaves.  Singling out a small fraction of the population for "reparations", presumably on the basis of appearance - since very few people could trace their ancestry that far back with any degree of certainty - is just pandering to racism.

Comment: @jamesqf: You're dodging the topic. This isn't about reparation for the entire concept of slavery and all of its historical victims. It's reparations for a specific instance of institutionalized slavery by a single nation, only a handful of generations ago, with a significant genealogical record.

Comment: @Flater: Sorry, but you're the one dodging the basic question.  How can you reasonably pay "reparations" when no one alive has been injured?

Comment: @jamesqf: Are you suggesting that if I steal your property and then you die (let's say your death is completely unrelated), that I cannot be guilty of stealing your property since you've ceased to exist, and your descendants have no basis for getting their lost inheritance back?

Comment: @Flater: Yes, if the theft is far enough in the past.  For a parallel example, consider the chances of the descendants of say John D. Rockefeller being sued, today, over some of his deals?  Especially ones which were perfectly legal at the time, though they'd be illegal today.

Comment: @jamesqf Its not just for slavery, it's for Jim Crow and lynchings and all the other injustice that still keeps Black people down today.

Comment: @Paul Johnson: And who have I, or almost anyone alive today, lynched?  Likewise, if there's injustice today, it seems to go the other way.

Comment: @jamesqf Because being arrested for Driving While White is totally a common experience these days.

Comment: @Paul Johnson: You think it's not?  Especially if you're a poor, young white male.  Happened to me, twice.  (Plus a number of harassment stops where I wasn't actually hauled off to jail.)  Also,  if you look at some of the more recently publicized cases, you'll find that either the photos of the victims have been manipulated, or the media, BLM, &c are claiming some obviously white people as being black.  Just as they claim that things which pretty much all poor people experience, regardless of their race, are down to racism.

Answer (score 46):

### No, on two counts

First, if they were funded by reorganization of current government spending, reparations would legally be no different from any other government program that targets a group.

This was established in [*Nixon v. Administrator of General Services*](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/433/425/#tab-opinion-1952361), that a law burdening a group is not unconstitutional.

> However expansive is the prohibition against bills of attainder, it was not intended to serve as a variant of the Equal Protection Clause, invalidating every Act by Congress or the States that burdens some persons or groups but not all other plausible individuals.

There's a little bit more about how intent to punish and legitimate purposes also matter.

Further, even were they funded by a specific additional tax, reparations would legally be considered a tax, not a punishment. Note that *everyone* would likely be taxed, but, as with many existing government programs, the proceeds would not be distributed back to everyone evenly.

Finally, reparations have been implemented by law previously in US history, for instance in the case of the [internment of Japanese-Americans.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internment_of_Japanese_Americans) To the best of my knowledge, there was no challenge on constitutional grounds, and if there was, it clearly was not successful.

Comment: But (1) the internment camps were built and run by the US federal government, whereas most slaves were privately-owned, and (2) the reparations were authorized "only" 43 years after the war, with many of the actual internees still alive.

Comment: The prohibition against bills of attainder may not be intended to serve as a variant of the Equal Protection Clause... but _the Equal Protection Clause_ is certainly a variant of the Equal Protection Clause. The 'reparations' proposed by Harris and Warren might not run afoul of the ban on bills of attainder, but they would almost certainly run afoul of the Equal Protection Clause itself unless they were actually based on being a descendant of a slave rather than on race.

Comment: The reparations for interned Japanese-Americans is a different matter entirely, as it was paid to people who were actually directly victims of illegal governmental action (i.e. the actual detainees themselves,) not to just anyone with Japanese heritage or who identified racially as Japanese.

Comment: @reirab - I find that highly unlikely. The Equal Protection Clause does *not* prevent bills that are narrowly scoped to serve a legitimate governmental purpose, even if they explicitly provide benefits to one group or another. That's why you can pass a law that explicitly benefits low income people (Medicaid), or elderly people (Social Security), or elderly people and people with disabilities (Medicare).

Comment: @Obie2.0 Racial discrimination isn't a legitimate governmental purpose. SS, in theory, is supposed to benefit everyone. The idea was to set up a retirement system. Of course, the reality is another story and it's really probably not legal either (which is why FDR had to threaten to stack the Supreme Court in order to prevent it from being struck down.) Though it's illegality would be more due to the lack of any Constitutional power of Congress authorizing it than violation of Equal Protection. If reparations were based on actual slave ancestry rather than race, then they might pass muster.

Comment: It doesn't preclude the existence of the Federal Women's Program, either.

Comment: @reirab - I think the law would be passed with the stated goal of reducing poverty among black Americans and decreasing wealth inequality, and if passed would almost certainly be upheld based on the existence of various similar programs.

Comment: If your argument is that reparations is as unconstitutional as *Social Security*, I hope you can see how likely a ruling against it would be, whatever your personal legal analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91946/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-reirab).

Answer (score 10):

It depends how they do it.  Some legal (although there may be other challenges for these) ways:

1. Pass a law saying that descendants of slaves could sue descendants of slave owners.  Then hold a trial or trials.  Would have to be carefully worded to not be [ex post facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_post_facto_law#United_States) banned.
2. Raise a general tax and make a specific payment.  So all races would pay a tax but only descendants of slaves would get money back.
3. Raise a general tax (possibly progressive) and make a means-tested payment.  So all races would pay tax and all races would receive payments.  But richer whites would pay more tax and poorer blacks would receive more payments.

The bill of attainder ban only prevents an explicit transfer of money from one group to the government without a trial.  It doesn't prevent implicit transfers; otherwise, welfare payments would trigger it.

Comment: The defense I would use against such a lawsuit is not ex post facto, but corruption of blood.

Comment: @Joshua: Could that be avoided by the lawsuit being against the estate rather than against the living descendant? Is it possible to have a judgement against the estate of someone whose wealth was inherited long ago, possibly separated by more than one generation of inheritance, resulting in a debt for some living person?

Comment: @R..: Which will, conveniently, limit the recoverable value to the value of the estate at its smallest inheritance.

Comment: This would be interesting in implementation (looking at it as a non-American).  Since slavery ended 150 years ago, there is no telling the financial status of the descendants of former slave-owners today.  It is exceptionally easy to completely annihilate vast magnitudes of wealth exceedingly quickly; one need only look at the financial status of lottery winners to see examples, and I doubt most former slave owners would have had even that kind of wealth.  If a system were to be enacted whereby descendants of slaves could sue descendants of slave owners, how would such a payment be calculated?

Comment: I don't think the lawsuit idea is a very common proposal. Unlike taxes, it *would* encounter legal issues, as well as more practical issues. For instance, lawsuits against estates are barred after more than one year. Such a proposal would only make sense if the idea actually were what the querent assumes, to punish the descendents of former slave-holders, which isn't the case. More typical reasoning has to do with compensation or reduction of the racial wealth disparity.

Comment: @Obie2.0: I agree that it seems impractical, but the idea not to "punish" descendants, but instead to remove the unfair advantage they continue to enjoy derived directly from the wealth accumulated through enslaved labor, seems appealing *in principle*.

Comment: I highly doubt there's much inherited "wealth accumulated through enslaved labor" still around today.  Slave owners got no financial compensation their freed slaves, the Confederate Dollar became worthless, and tangible assets were vulnerable to wartime looting or destruction.  I guess the plantation land itself would be worth something.  Still, how many present-day billionaires do you know of who got their family fortune by owning slaves?

Comment: @dan04 - I don't think your assessment is correct. First, land was worth more than "something." A small farm can have over $100,000 worth of land value. Second, wartime looting existed, but it's a leap to say it would destroy most tangible goods without further evidence. Third, banks did exist back then, and many plantation owners had money in those banks (it wasn't all in Confederate Dollars...even mostly). Finally, many of those same enslaved individuals continued to be exploited via the sharecropping system, using infrastructure built while slavery was legal, further enriching these people.

Comment: The mention of billionaires is an appeal to extremes: billionaires are not representative of the population, and many of the largest fortunes are recent. It's also a little optimistic to imagine that fortunes from a mere century and a half ago were wiped out. The famous Rockefellers, say, are still a wealthy family.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Yeah, but the Rockefellers were/are Yankee (mostly New York) industrialists and bankers.  Where are the fortunes of [Joshua Ward or Stephen Duncan](https://sites.rootsweb.com/~ajac/biggest16.htm) today?

Comment: @dan04 - It's very difficult to establish how much of their fortunes survived into the present day, both because Northern industrialists were genuinely richer, and because many families have been hesitant to emphasize a fortune derived from slavery. However, I can confirm that Stephen Duncan's heirs were wealthy enough in 1911 to have a [mansion and grounds](https://web.archive.org/web/20100923184511/http://www.natchezguesthouse.com/photos/duncan-room.htm), which might have been worth a little had they not gotten rid of it.

Comment: #1 presents amusing possibilities.  There are undoubtedly a good many individuals who are descendants of both slave owners and former slaves: do these people sue themselves?  This just points up a practical problem.  The Civil War ended over 150 years ago, so figuring 25 years per generation, that's 64 CW-era ancestors per person.  How many people even know (or care) who their great-grandparents were?  I sure don't.  (Even if you do geneology, there are plenty of people whose parentage doesn't exactly match records :-))

Comment: @jamesqf also, provi

Answer (score 6):

1. Since no reparations proposal requires anyone to be disenfranchised,
   whipped, branded, imprisoned, or executed... it's not clear in what
   sense, (if any), *"punishment"* might be construed as occurring in
   the event of reparations. If one of the premises of this question is
   the exotic notion that all taxation is *"punishment"*, this should
   be clearly stated in the question. If not, then there's no
   punishment, and the question is moot.
2. Since there's absolutely no question of the fact of slavery, or so much of its
   unhappy aftermath, a trial for slavery would seem as pointless as
   having a trial to decide whether or not some disastrous tornado or
   hurricane had occurred.

Combining the previous two points, this question is like asking whether [federal assistance for victims of California's wildfires](https://www.fema.gov/news-release/2018/12/12/4407/180-million-grants-and-loans-approved-wildfire-survivors) violates the prohibition against Bills of Attainder because rendering such assistance would unconstitutionally "punish" the innocent citizens of [Hawaii and Louisiana](https://www.currentresults.com/Weather-Extremes/US/wettest-states.php).

---

Generalizing:  some disasters are caused by nature; some disasters are man-made like oil spills, great fires, great errors, harmful policies, wars, *etc.*; both types of disasters create victims, refugees, impoverishment, blight, and assorted lasting dangers to public safety and health.

Neglect doesn't scale up well; governmental neglect metaphorically unties [those heraldic bundles of sticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasces#Federal_fasces_iconography), and in letting a few break, weakens the remaining bundle.  In which sense governments that ignore and neglect disasters inadvertently invite and invest in additional disasters.

Comment: While point 1 certainly is true, the argument would be that a disparate tax might effectively constitute a fine, which can be a (mild) form of punishment. I don't think this is correct, because intent is important, as is the presence of a legitimate political purpose, but that would be the argument.

Comment: @Obie2.0, I had appreciated that implied imputation, but it yet remains unclear as to the logical validity of the overall notion in the mind of the question's author.  Fines are for reducing the frequency of certain minor crimes of negligence, but slavery was no careless misdemeanor.

Comment: @agc: Slavery was *legal*.  Charging fines for it would violate the Constitutional prohibition against *ex post facto* laws.

Comment: @dan04 - Indeed, but no one really is proposing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call them "reparations" and then say they're a tax.  The word "Reparations" means, [according to Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/reparation):

> the making of amends for a wrong one has done, by paying money to or otherwise helping those who have been wronged.

We don't use taxes to "make amends".

Comment: The question doesn't use the word tax, can you elaborate?

Comment: While the source you linked uses a person-to-person example, history provides another: after Germany lost WWI, the German government had to pay [war reparations](https://www.britannica.com/topic/reparations) to the Allied Powers to the (original) tune of $33 billion.  If the government were to pay, where else would that money come from besides taxes?

Answer (score -4):

You do realize what is legal or illegal, is often political

if it is politically acceptable, we will find a way to make it legal

if it is politically unacceptable, we will find a way to make it illegal.

why do you think men can walk around bare chested in america.. but women can't.

but women can wear bikini in america, but in saudi arabia they need to wear burqas...

Slavery was politically necessary at the founding of the nation, so it was legal, even Constitutional.

But then the civil war happened.  Emancipation became a good way to weaken the other side.  So Slavery became illegal.

Gold and silver used to be Constitutional legal tender.  Now it is just a relic of a barbaric past (because wars are very expensive)

A century ago, alcohol was illegal and unconstitutional.  Then it isn't.

Now weed is becoming legal.

If there is enough political momentum for Reparation.  It will be legal.  If there isn't, it won't be.

Comment: "why do you think men can walk around bare chested in america.. but women can't" - why do you think women can't? Because this exact case has been argued in court.